# LM2596 TO-263-5 or TO-263-6

Tags: power-supply, texas-instruments, kicad, footprint

Hi just a dumb question that I have to be sure.
I will be using [LM2596](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/LM2596SX-5.0-NOPB/LM2596SX-5.0-NOPBTR-ND/334927)

It is stated in its description: IC REG BUCK 5V 3A TO263-5
That its package is TO-263-5.
But on its package is TO-263-6, D²Pak (5 Leads + Tab), TO-263BA.

On the image, there are 5 leads and 1 tab. 
Is this the correct footprint for this?

[image]

Is Pin 3 also the TAB? which is a ground on typical applications.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two footprints available for the LM2596, the [KTT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/mpsf007e/mpsf007e.pdf) and the [NDH](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/mmsf011/mmsf011.pdf). This one looks like the KTT / TO-263 package. The tab should be connected to ground in addition to pin 3 being connected to ground.

Comment: So is it the right one to use for the KTT?

Comment: Yes, looks like it.